# Angular is adding extra directory on build in url

Tags: angular

I am building a new ng app `ng build --prod --base-href=XXXX` after success and deployment on live server `XXXX` is shown twice in url like `abc.com/XXXX/XXXX` and on refresh it throw 404 not found error. How can i fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this command:

```
ng build --prod --base-href="/XXXX/"
```